# Problem with "Transparent Huge Pages" on Windows 10 when using Docker

Tags: windows, docker, percona, huge-pages, tokudb

When running percona/percona-server:5.7 image and enable TokuDB it complained about transparent huge pages (THP) is enabled. However I have turned it off under:
"Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/lock-pages-in-memory

When I run the following line:

```
docker run --name ps -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e INIT_TOKUDB=yes  percona/percona-server:5.7
```

I get this error message:

```
Disabling transparent huge pages for the current session...
/usr/bin/ps-admin: line 708: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag:  Read-only file system
/usr/bin/ps-admin: line 711: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled: Read-only file system
ERROR: Failed to disable transparent huge pages for this session.
```

Any idea how to turn it off before starting the docker image?

I can see it is enabled in the:

```
bash-4.2$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always [madvise] never
```

Answer (score 0):

Which docker engine are you using?  Within Docker Desktop go to settings.  Then under the general section it will show `Use the WSL2 based engine`.  If this is checked then more than likely the issue is with using WSL2.

Additionally, look at your my.cnf file.  If the cnf file has the `thp-setting` in it, mysql  will try to write the setting that exists into those locations when it starts.  If you comment out or remove that line in my.cnf, it should work fine.